# Reset editMod mapedit in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-mapedit

I'm creating a R Shiny app using the drawing tools of mapedit through editMod() to run some operations (in the reprex below I simplified to just calculating the area of the drawn polygons). I have some troubles with the refresh button that I created (with an observeEvent). Basically I want this button to restart everything to 0, as if the user was getting to a new session. I managed to reinitialise the table and the leaflet map, but the drawn polygons are not removed.

To visualise my problem with the reprex below: 1) create a polygon, 2) click "Calculate area", 3) Click "Refresh", 4) Click "Calculate area". You'll see that the same area is calculated (ie edits()$finished still includes the polygons drawn in step 1).
I tried a number of things to reinitialise edits()$finished but always got messages saying I cannot edit that manually.

Any suggestion will be helpful! Thanks,
Victor

```
### Charge libraries
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(mapedit)
library(sf)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(DT)




#################
### Create UI ###
#################

ui<-shinyUI(
  
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(column(6, align="center", offset = 3,
                    actionButton("refresh", "Refresh", icon=icon("rotate-right"))
    )),
    
    sidebarLayout(
      
      # add map
      mainPanel(
        editModUI("map", height=600),
      ),
      # add results
      sidebarPanel(
        uiOutput("calc"),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.calc_button >= 1", # Show loader and results only if we clicked on calculate
                         withSpinner(DT::DTOutput('TableIndex'))
                         )
        )
      )
    )
  )






#####################
### Create server ###
#####################

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ### Create calculation button (in server rather than ui to be able to refresh easily)
  output$calc <- renderUI({
    actionButton("calc_button", "Calculate area", icon=icon("arrow-right"))
  })
  
  
  ### Create map
  observe({
    print("Create mapedit")
    
    Leaf<-leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 4)) %>%
      addTiles(group="OpenStreetMap") %>%
      addDrawToolbar(
        polylineOptions = FALSE,
        polygonOptions = drawPolygonOptions(),
        circleOptions = FALSE,
        rectangleOptions = FALSE,
        markerOptions = FALSE,
        circleMarkerOptions = FALSE,
        editOptions=editToolbarOptions(edit=TRUE, remove=TRUE)
      )
    
    edits <- callModule(
      editMod,
      leafmap = Leaf,
      id = "map"
    )

    
    ### Event: Calculate Area and print in table
    observeEvent(input$calc_button, {
      
      print("Calculate area")
      
      Area <- st_area(edits()$finished) %>% as.numeric(.) %>% round(.)
      
      output$TableIndex <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(data.frame(Index="Area (km2)", Value=Area), options = list(dom = 't'), rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE)
        })
      
        
    })
    
    
    ### Refresh the app: still a problem with edits (not emptied)
    observeEvent(input$refresh, {
      
      print("Reset the app")
      
      # Empty table
      output$TableIndex <- DT::renderDataTable({data.frame()})

      # Recreate map
      edits <- callModule(
        editMod,
        leafmap = Leaf,
        id = "map"
      )
    })
  })
}



###########
### RUN ###
###########

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a disaster: you should never nest an observer inside an observer, and you should avoid nesting an output slot inside an observer.

That said, it was really not easy. I have only been able to find a solution resorting to JavaScript.

```r
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(mapedit)
library(sf)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(DT)
library(htmlwidgets)

#################
### Create UI ###
#################

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("refresh", "Refresh map", icon = icon("rotate-right")),
      br(),
      actionButton("calc_button", "Calculate area", icon = icon("arrow-right")),
      br(),
      withSpinner(DTOutput("TableIndex"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      editModUI("map", height = 600)
    )
  )
)

#####################
### Create server ###
#####################

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # leaflet object
  Leaf <- leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 4)) %>%
    addTiles(group = NULL) %>%
    addDrawToolbar(
      polylineOptions = FALSE,
      polygonOptions = drawPolygonOptions(),
      circleOptions = FALSE,
      rectangleOptions = FALSE,
      markerOptions = FALSE,
      circleMarkerOptions = FALSE,
      editOptions = editToolbarOptions(edit = TRUE, remove = TRUE)
    ) %>%
    onRender("function(el, x){
               var map = this;
               var polygons = [];
               map.on('layeradd', function(e) {
                 polygons.push(e.layer);
               });
               $('#refresh').on('click', function() {
                 var features = [];
                 for(var polygon of polygons) {
                   if(polygon.feature) {
                     features.push(polygon);
                     map.removeLayer(polygon);
                   }
                 }
                 polygons = [];
                 var group = L.layerGroup(features);
                 var collection = group.toGeoJSON(false);
                 var n = collection.features.length;
                 var i = 0;
                 var interval = setInterval(function() {
                    if(i === n) {
                      clearInterval(interval);
                    } else {
                      var f = collection.features[i];
                      var deleted = {type: 'FeatureCollection', features: [f]};
                      Shiny.setInputValue(el.id + '_draw_deleted_features', deleted);
                      i = i + 1;
                    }
                 });
               });
             }")
  
  # call module
  edits <- callModule(
    editMod,
    leafmap = Leaf,
    id = "map",
    record = FALSE,
    sf = TRUE
  )
  
  # dataframe for the table displaying the areas
  Dat <- reactiveVal()
  
  # calculate areas on clicking the button
  observeEvent(input$calc_button, {
    req(edits()$finished)
    Area <- st_area(edits()$finished) %>% as.numeric(.) %>% round(.)
    Dat(data.frame(Index = "Area (km2)", Value = Area))
  })
  
  # the table displaying the areas
  output$TableIndex <- renderDT({
    req(Dat())
    datatable(Dat(), options = list(dom = "t"), rownames = FALSE)
  })
  
  # on clicking the 'refresh' button, empty the dataframe
  observeEvent(input$refresh, {
    Dat(NULL)
  })
  
}

###########
### RUN ###
###########
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's super helpful! Regarding the code disaster, thanks as well! I'll keep that it mind and work on it!